# How to match a lookbehind of exactly 1 or 2 line break(s) or newline(s)?

Tags: python, regex

I'm using this regex - `(?s)Must to have((?!(\r?\n){2}).)*` to match and capture the para directly following 'Must to have'. Like you can see the requirement of matching this para until the first double line break or \n\n is already met. I want to achieve the same with the lookbehind part i.e exactly one or two newlines then 'Must to have' and the rest until a \n\n. I've observed that (?s) matches even if there's no \n before. Please help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've observed that (?s) matches even if there's no \n before.

`(?s)` is an inline flag which turns on `re.DOTALL` mode so `.` matches newlines, it doesn't match anything itself.

> I want to achieve the same with the lookbehind part i.e exactly one or two newlines then 'Must to have'....

To match "Must to have" at the start of a line, you can just use `^`, for example

```py
(?sm)^Must to have((?!(?:\r?\n){2}).)*
```

Notice that I added the `m` flag in `(?sm)`, to turn on `re.MULTILINE` mode so that `^` matches at the beginning of the string *and* at the beginning of each line.

Comment: @Ashutosh Note that this will match `Must to have` right at the begining of the string which you did not say you wanted to do.

Comment: yes my bad, the question framed the new way is easier to wrap your head around, I was thinking differently before.